# how to count the same column from 1x793 struct1 field and each row has axb, I want to count how many b1, b2, b3

Tags: matlab

I have Matlab data of  1x793 struct with1 field each row axb (a or b=1,2,3...etc) how can I count how many for b1,b2,b3,b4 in this case I ignore a value?

Comment: What have you tried? Show your code, and learn [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi, I used count_unique (build in matlab code) but it does not work. my data is 1x793 struct or cell, row 1=1x35 double, row 2=1x61 double, row 3=2x31 double....row793=1x1. I want to count how many occurrence for nx61, nx60 to nx1. Thanks

Comment: So, what is going wrong with that? Specify your question.

Comment: I have no idea what code I should use in this case. Please kindly advice if you know how to solve this. thanks

Comment: You could at least show us a sample of your struct and your desired output. Right now, I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: I have data 1x1000 struct with 1 field , row1=1x61 double, row 2=2x50 double, row 3=3x31double, row4=[5,4], row5=[50,55,53]...row 1000=2. I want to make a plot of how many counts for nx61, nx50.....nx2,nx1 in this case if every row is nxm then m value(1....61), i will put 1x61,2x62,3x61..nx61 into 1 group of data. I am hoping to get 61 data in total.thanks

Comment: I agree it's badly asked question and the op needs to read more about posting format and rules. I feel she may have very little knowledge about Matlab and she doesn't even care to study it but just want to get the job done quickly. If she didn't respond to my answer then I will withdraw it.

Comment: @Y.Y.Chang, I am really sorry for late reply. Thank you so much for your answer. I have no background in matlab. so I am trying my best. your answer is really appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First find the size of all 2D `array` in your struct variable.

**Hint:**

```
structfun
```

By far you should have a *`1x1000`* `cell` variable with *`1x2`* array in each element. Now, let's convert it to a table variable

**Hint:**

```
cell2table
```

With a `table` variable, it's easy now to sort out the occurrence of each array size

**Hint:**

```
unique
```

Finally, count the frequency of each occurrence

**Hint:**

```
histcounts
```

Comment: I run structfun but from Matlab, I got Error using structfun beacuse
Inputs to STRUCTFUN must be scalar a=structfun(@(x)histc(x.trackFeatIndxCG,1:869),tracks1,'UniformOutput',false);
thanks

Comment: You are not following. I indicated you need to use `structfun` to find the size of array in each raw of you struct, not mess all the functions I provided around into one line. That won't work. Did you read the documentation? Type `help structfun`, `help histc` to find out

Comment: I did and I got your concept. my code a=structfun(@size,tracks1) , i still got error because the input must be scalar structures. PS: thank you so much I have learned a lot from you. appreciate it.

Comment: Try this `a = structfun(@size,track1,'UniformOutput',false)` and then convert a to cell with `struct2cell`

Comment: I finally go it.Thanks you so much@Y.Y.Chang. You are excellent, my code  
>> a=cellfun(@size,tracksFeatIndxCG,'uniformOutput',false);
>> b=cell2table(a);
>> b = [table(b.a(:,1),'VariableNames',{'a1'}),table(b.a(:,2),'VariableNames',{'a2'})];
>> a2 = b{:,2};
>> a3=histc(a2,unique(a2));

Comment: Cool. I am glad you finally get it.